# Understanding the factorization of subleading soft contributions-massless QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, spinors, research-level

I am reading [The SAGEX Review on Scattering Amplitudes Chapter 11: Soft Theorems and Celestial Amplitudes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.13022.pdf). In subsection 2.2, the subleading soft photon theorem is derived. The result is

$$A^{\mu}=\sum_{i=1}^nQ_i
\bigg[
\frac{\eta_ip_i^{\mu}}{\delta (q\cdot p_i)}+
\frac{q^{\nu}p_i^{\mu}}{(q\cdot p_i)}
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i^{\nu}}-
\frac{iq_{\nu}S_i^{\mu\nu}}{(q\cdot p_i)}-
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{i\mu}}
\bigg]
\mathcal{A}(p)+\mathcal{O}(\delta)
\label{1}\tag{1}$$

and the following text is given:

> where we can now view the derivatives as acting on the full amplitude but $S_i^{\mu\nu}$ should
> be then understood to be in the appropriate representation for the $i$-th external particle including the cancelling contribution from passing the spinor wavefunction through the action of the momentum derivatives

What is the meaning of the paragraph above and which is the appropriate representation for the $i$-th external particle?

**MY ATTEMPT:** To determine the subleading contribution from the soft theorem, I study a generic amplitude, in which a soft photon is emitted by an external line of momentum $p$. The amplitude describing the interaction at hand, not accompanied, though, by the soft photon emission, is

$$i\mathcal{M}_0=i\mathcal{T}(p) u_s(p)$$

where $i\mathcal{T}(p)$ is an amplitude that is stripped of the spinor $u_s(p)$ and $s$ is the polarization index of the massless fermion.

Adding a photon in the final state particles alters the amplitude in the following way
$$i\mathcal{M}_0\rightarrow i\mathcal{M}_{\text{tree}}=
i\mathcal{T}(p-k)\frac{e}{(-2p\cdot k)} 
(-\not{p}+\not{k})\not{\epsilon}^*_{\lambda}(k)
u_s(p)$$

I now have three contributions

1. Leading contribution: can be derived if I set $k=0$ in $i\mathcal{T}(p-k)$ and take the leading term in the additional fermion propagator
2. Subleading contributions associated with the orbital angular momentum operator: those can be determined by Taylor expanding $i\mathcal{T}(p-k)$ in powers of $k$.
3. Subleading contributions associated with the spin angular momentum operator: those can be determined by setting $k=0$ in $i\mathcal{T}(p-k)$ and by taking the subleading contribution from the additional fermion propagator.

I wish to focus on deriving the spin contribution. To do that, I neglect the contribution that is proportional to $\not{p}$ and therefore after using that $2\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}=\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}+
[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$, we have

$$i\mathcal{M}_{\text{tree}}^{(\text{spin})}=
\frac{(-e)}{2(-2p\cdot k)}\epsilon^*_{\mu\lambda}(k)k_{\nu}\
i\mathcal{T}(p) 
[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]\
u_s(p)$$

**MY OBSERVATIONS OR THOUGHTS:**

1. The difference between Eq. (\ref{1}) and my attempt is that in Eq. (\ref{1}) there exists the spin operator in the subleading contribution, whereas in my attempt, I have the commutator of two Dirac matrices. Perhaps if I choose a representation, my answer reduces to Eq. (\ref{1}). **Is this true?**
2. If not, the I may be missing something, because the remaining terms of the subleading soft photon theorem are present in my attempt. So, what am I missing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'll give a minor advice. It often happens that when we want to prove something there are two possible paths: (1) use less formalism and end up writing down a longer and often clumsy and less enlightening proof, or (2) learn more advanced techniques and find out that with this extra formalism it is possible to write a more concise and more instructive proof of the claim. I always opted for (2). So in this particular case I would indeed advise that you do what you suggested in (5).

Comment: Of course it should be possible to do it without those techniques but it will be hard and more confusing. To give an example of what I mean: in several fields it is possible to do several things without differential geometry, but doing so only leads to clumsy analyses. Why would one want to do so? Something may be possible and yet inconvenient.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gold, I have already started learning about (5), but I would also want to understand this in the more conventional approach of standard diagrammatic techniques.

Comment: I started believing that there is some representation for the spinors, in which the 4d spinors with complex entries are represented by 8d vectors with real entries, and therefore, somehow, the desired factorization takes place. I would like to learn more though